# HTTP_DELETE error - Request method for this URI is not handled by server

Tags: esp32

Good afternoon fellow programmers, could you clarify a doubt for me.

I'm create a rest and pasted a snippet of the code.  if you have this information to help me I would appreciate it.
**The get, put, post methods are working perfectly when I test in the post man, but the delete method when tested gives the following message:**

Request method for this URI is not handled by server

**Do you know if expressif has not implemented it?**

Thank you very much

```
esp_err_t getTest(httpd_req_t *request) {
    httpd_resp_set_status(request, "200 Ok");
    httpd_resp_set_hdr(request, "Content-Type", "text/html");
    httpd_resp_sendstr(request, "test get");

    return ESP_OK;
}
esp_err_t putTest(httpd_req_t *request) {
    httpd_resp_set_status(request, "201 Created");
    httpd_resp_set_hdr(request, "Content-Type", "text/html");
    httpd_resp_sendstr(request, "test Put");

    return ESP_OK;
}
esp_err_t postTest(httpd_req_t *request) {
    httpd_resp_set_status(request, "200 Ok");
    httpd_resp_set_hdr(request, "Content-Type", "text/html");
    httpd_resp_sendstr(request, "test Post");

    return ESP_OK;
}
esp_err_t testDelete(httpd_req_t *request) {
    httpd_resp_set_status(request, "201 Created");
    httpd_resp_set_hdr(request, "Content-Type", "text/html");
    httpd_resp_sendstr(request, "test delete");

    return ESP_OK;
}

const httpd_uri_t get_uri = {
    .uri = "/api/testWs",
    .method = HTTP_GET,
    .handler = testGet,
    .user_ctx = NULL
};
const httpd_uri_t put_uri = {
    .uri = "/api/testWs",
    .method = HTTP_PUT,
    .handler = testPut,
    .user_ctx = NULL
};
const httpd_uri_t post_uri = {
    .uri = "/api/testWs",
    .method = HTTP_POST,
    .handler = testPost,
    .user_ctx = NULL
};
const httpd_uri_t delete_uri = {
    .uri = "/api/testWs",
    .method = HTTP_DELETE,
    .handler = testDelete,
    .user_ctx = NULL
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled the uri in the DELETE handler. You used `/api/testWs` everywhere else and `/api/testeWs` for DELETE.

Comment: thank you very much mate but I already fixed it and it keeps giving the same error, I don't know if espressif implemented this HTTP_DELETE method because it's the only one that isn't working the other 3 HTTP_GET, HTTP_POST, HTTP_PUT work without problem

Comment: I managed to get it right mate, I ended up forgetting to put .uri = "/api/testWs/*"
everything working now, thank you very much